# Hide running Java window?

Tags: java, windows

How can I hide a .jar file when its running. I mean I don't want it to be displayed as a window where all the other windows are running at the bottom of the screen.

Can this easily be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downloaded Clicky Gone which can hide any active window. It was already running with javaw.exe and wasn't hidden.

Answer (score 2):

run with javaw.exe instead of java.exe